# Switch Maven version after installing from jpackage?

Tags: centos, software-installation, configuration

I've installed `maven3` on CentOS from the JPackage repository. Problem is my installs also seem to have pulled in `maven2` which is the default. Is there any way to switch `/usr/bin/mvn` to be maven3? perhaps using the `alternatives` application? (note: I can modify the path, or symlink I know, just trying to find out if there's a more correct way)

Comment: What version of CentOS?

Comment: vagrant chef/CentOS-6.5

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `maven` packages and just install the `maven3` packages. This is only going to give you 3.0.3, however.

- http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/6.0/generic/free/repoview/maven3.html

If you want to get a more recent version of Maven I'd go with [dchen's repo](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6/x86_64/) from the "Fedora People" unofficial repositories. It seems to be tracking the latest version, [`apache-maven-3.2.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm`](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6/x86_64/apache-maven-3.2.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm). Here's [the top level link](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/) to dchen's repository as well.

#### References

- [How to install Maven into Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298865/how-to-install-maven-into-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6)

Comment: I think something else is pulling in `maven` haven't checked what. This is an entirely new image, built from vagrant. 3.0.3 is just enough in our case.

Comment: @xenoterracide - `rpm -q --whatrequires maven2`?

Comment: that's a list of about 30 entries, but caused in the middle of `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel maven3 tomcat7`

Comment: @xenoterracide - sounds like you're stuck with it then. I would utilize `alternatives` at this point if you cannot physically remove it.

Comment: that's kind of what the question was about, I couldn't figure out how to make alternatives do this honestly. (my first hack was just to modify the path)

Comment: @xenoterracide - I usually start by listing out the executables that are included in a  given RPM and then develop custom `alternatives` commands against the package. I've never seen prescribed method for doing this.